# I'm looking to find an average difference between a series of 2 rows same column in SQL

Tags: sql, row, average

So I've looked through a lot of questions about subtraction and all that for SQL but haven't found the exact same use.

I'm using a single table and trying to find an average response time between two people talking on my site. Here's the data sample:

```
id      created_at          conversation_id sender_id   receiver_id
307165  2017-05-03 20:03:27 96557           24          1755
307166  2017-05-03 20:04:22 96557           1755        24
303130  2017-04-20 18:03:53 102458          2518        4475
302671  2017-04-18 20:11:20 102505          3100        1079
302670  2017-04-18 20:09:38 103014          3100        2676
350570  2017-09-18 20:59:56 103496          5453        929
290458  2017-02-16 13:38:47 103575          2841        2282
300001  2017-04-08 16:42:16 104159          2740        1689
304204  2017-04-24 17:31:25 104531          5963        1118
284873  2017-01-12 22:33:19 104712          3657        3967
284872  2017-01-12 22:31:38 104712          3967        3657
```

What I want is to find an Average Response Time based on the conversation_id

Comment: Please add the database you're using to the question tags and edit your question to show what you expect the output to be for the data shown. Also, please show your attempt at the query and how it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CTE will take care of bringing the conversation start and end into the same row.
Then use `DATEDIFF` to compute the response time, and average it. 
Assumes there are only ever two entries per conversation (ignores others with 1 or more than 2).

```
WITH X AS (
    SELECT conversation_id, MIN(created_at) AS convstart, MAX(created_at) AS convend
    FROM theTable
    GROUP BY conversation_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) 
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(second,convstart,convend)) AS AvgResponse
FROM X
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . You can get the "response" for a given row by getting the next row between the two conversers.  The rest is getting the average -- which is database dependent.

Something like this:

```
select avg(next_created_at - created_at) -- exact syntax depends on the database
from (select m.*,
             (select min(m2.created_at)
              from messages m2
              where m2.sender_id = m.receiver_id and m.sender_id = m2.receiver_id and
                    m2.conversation_id = m.conversation_id and
                    m2.created_at > m.created_at
             ) next_created_at
      from messages m
     ) mm
where next_created_at is not null;
```